# How do you deeply replace certain objects with a child value in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have data that comes with localization I don't need:

`title: {'en-US': 'Example Title}`

I want to create a function that turns all localization objects into a string.

`title: 'Example Title'`

Which lodash methods would be helpful for this?

Comment: can you add a sample of the data array / Object ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your example data, you can use `_.mapValues()` with the property name of the translation you want:

```js
const data = {
  title: {'en-US': 'Example Title'}
}

const result = _.mapValues(data, 'en-US')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects with that structure, and the locations might all be different, here's how you might approach it with lodash:

```js
const data = [{id:11,title:{'en-US':'Example Title 11'}},{id:12,title:{'tr-TR':'Example Title 12'}},{id:13,title:{'en-GB':'Example Title 13'}}];

function removeLocation(data) {
  return _.map(data, obj => {
    const key = _.keys(obj.title)[0];
    return { ...obj, title: obj.title[key] };
  });
}

console.log(removeLocation(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But if you're going to do that you may as well save yourself a few KB and use the native JS methods:

```js
const data = [{id:11,title:{'en-US':'Example Title 11'}},{id:12,title:{'tr-TR':'Example Title 12'}},{id:13,title:{'en-GB':'Example Title 13'}}];

function removeLocation(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    const key = Object.keys(obj.title)[0];
    return { ...obj, title: obj.title[key] };
  });
}

console.log(removeLocation(data));
```